# Alternative content for HTML5 canvas

Tags: html, canvas, fallback

Simple question: If I have a setup like `<canvas><img src="alternative.png" /></canvas>`, then a browser that doesn't support `<canvas>` will load the image. The question is, will a browser that DOES support `<canvas>` load the image, even if the image will never be displayed? Or will it simply ignore the tag?

Comment: Have you tried it? It's trivial to test with for example Firebug or Chrome's dev tools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes they do.  It's even possible to display an image in the fallback content [in the `canvas` itself](http://jsfiddle.net/robertc/HnHjT/).

Answer (score 0):

Content in the canvas sub DOM is not really fallback content as it can be accessed by assistive technology users when canvas is supported in the browser, also if focusable interactive content is included in the sub DOM then it will be included in the default tab order and users can activate it using the keyboard. Details of this, examples and videos of of this in action are provided in [HTML5 Canvas Accessibility in Firefox 13](http://www.paciellogroup.com/blog/2012/06/html5-canvas-accessibility-in-firefox-13/)